# How To Send Delayed BroadcastReceiver After X Seconds

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a single class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and in the `onReceive` method of this class I have this code:

```
Intent autoBoostIntent = new Intent();
autoBoostIntent.setAction(Values.ACTION_AUTO_BOOST);
context.sendBroadcast(autoBoostIntent);
```

Which serves the purspose of re-calling the same BroadcastReceiver class over and over with a specific `action`. The problem is, that I want to delay the above procedure, so the broadcast is sent every 10 seconds for example. Is this possible?

**Edit:** I want the broadcast to loop indefinitely, regardless if the device is awake (keyboard unlocked) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms you could just add a `Thread.sleep(10000)` to your code, which will cause the Thread to sleep for 10 seconds before it continues with the next action.

If you are using `BroadcastReceivers` though, you could extend your application to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class, which will fire a broadcast at a set time (which you can programmatically set to be 10 seconds from now).

Or you could use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: +1 for the AlarmManager which as a setRepeatingAlarm method. BroadcastReceivers are not allowed to run long (I believe the time limit is 10 seconds). If they run longer than this time they will be killed by the OS. So Handlers and sleeping the thread may be unreliable. Also, using Thread.sleep() on the UI Thread may cause your app to become unresponsive to the user.

Comment: `Also, using Thread.sleep() on the UI Thread may cause your app to become unresponsive to the user.`. It will. :)

Comment: ..And also AlarmMAnager is not recommended for short intervals.
Use async task (with handler) with a delay instead.